# El siguiente script en PHP no logra subir los archivos al servidor

Tags: php

Tengo un servidor en en cual ya configuré las carpetas para la escritura por parte de mi usuario, incluso tengo un segundo script que edita los registros y este si sube los archivos, no comprendo que es lo que está mal en mi script, se los dejó, quizá alguien puede apoyarme.

```
<?php
    
    require 'conexion.php';
    
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $estado_civil = $_POST['estado_civil'];
    $hijos = isset($_POST['hijo']) ? $_POST['hijos'] : 0;
    $intereses = isset($_POST['intereses']) ? $_POST['intereses'] : null;
    
    $arrayIntereses = null;
    
    $num_array = count($intereses);
    $contador = 0;
    
    if($num_array>0){
        foreach ($intereses as $key => $value) {
            if ($contador != $num_array-1)
            $arrayIntereses .= $value.' ';
            else
            $arrayIntereses .= $value;
            $contador++;
        }
    }
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, correo, telefono, estado_civil, hijos, intereses) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$telefono', '$estado_civil', '$hijos', '$arrayIntereses')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;
    
    if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){
        
        } else {
        
        $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpeg","image/jpg","application/pdf");
        $limite_kb = 500000; 
        
        if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 500000){
            
            $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
            
            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
            }
            
            if(!file_exists($archivo)){
                
                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);
                
                if($resultado){
                    echo "Archivo Guardado";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error al guardar archivo";
                }
                
                } else {
                echo "Archivo ya existe";
            }
            
            } else {
            echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
        }
        
    }
    
?>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row text-center">
                <?php if($resultado) { ?>
                    <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Para quien pueda apoyarme, muchas gracias

Ya configure las carpetas, y como lo digo arriba el script que edita los registros si permite subir archivos, pero simplemente no veo que está mal en el codigo.

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer ni el contexto. ¿De dónde tomas los supuestos archivos que quieres subir? ¿Qué tiene que ver la sentencia INSERT con esto? Convendría que revises el log de errores en busca de pistas sobre lo que está fallando.

Comment: Deberías de compartir el código `HTML` que envía la acción al código de arriba para que podamos entender mejor qué puede estar causando el problema. Te recomiendo también que pongas arriba de `conexion.php` la siguiente línea de código: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` además de revisar el log de errores.